# Determine eigenvectors and eigenvalues for the following 3x3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The task is: Determine eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors for the following matrix:

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -3 & 3 \newline
3 & -5 & 3 \newline
6 & -6 & 4
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^3_3$

I know how to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for a 2x2 matrix, but all the tutorials I found online use factorization to get the eigenvalues for a 3x3 that my brain cannot really transfer onto this problem.

When calculating $det(A - \lambda I)$ I am left with $-\lambda^3 + 66\lambda + 16 = 0$. How do I go from there?

Help would greatly be appreciated!

Best regards

Comment: Have you tried computing the eigenvalues?

Comment: Compute $\det(A-\lambda I)$, and solve it for $\lambda$ to get the eigenvalues. Do you know how to calculate the determinant in general?

Comment: Edit: Added my progress in computing the eigenvalues

Comment: Hint: $-8$ is a root.

Comment: The rational root theorem says that if a polynomial $a_nx^n+\dots+a_1x+a_0$ has a rational root $x=\frac{p}{q}$, then $p$ has to divide $a_0$ and $q$ has to divide $a_n$. Usually example problems will have "nice" roots, so this is extremely useful in most cases! So in your case, the only rational roots that are possible are: $\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 4, \pm 8$, and indeed, $x_1=-8$ does work. Simply factor it out using polynomial division to get a quadratic which you can solve, getting the two remaining roots of $x_{2,3}= 4 \pm 3\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: the 66 is wrong, you need to find the correct characteristic polynomial

Comment: In what way does doing it in 2x2 differ from doing it in 3x3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned twice by Will Jagy in the comments, your 66 is wrong. The characteristic polynomial is
$$P(\lambda):=\det(A-\lambda I)=-\lambda^3+12\lambda+16.$$
By the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), one easily finds that $-2$ and $4$ are roots and finally,
$$P(\lambda)=-(\lambda-4)(\lambda+2)^2.$$
An eigenvector for $4$ is e.g.
$$u:=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\2\end{pmatrix}.$$
At this stage, we still don't know if $A$ is diagonalizable. The eigenspace for $-2$ could be of dimension only $1.$ Actually, the calculation shows it is of dimension $2:$ two independent eigenvectors for $-2$ are (for instance)
$$v:=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix},\quad w:=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}.$$
So, $A$ is diagonalizable and $(u,v,w)$ is an *eigen*basis for it (your question "basis for $A$" has been meanwhile corrected).